# Qt Mac OS Deployment - You must supply an Apple ID

Tags: macos, qt, deployment, app-store-connect

I have developed a Mac OS app in `Qt 5.2.1`. I have used `macdeployqt`, signed frameworks and plugins, signed the app and made a package.

When I use `Application Loader` to upload the `pkg` file, after a while, I get an error message `You must supply an Apple ID`.

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: Well, did you supply a correct Apple ID to the application loader upon startup?

Comment: How have you generated the .pkg? Can you share the steps to do it? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

I find that I need to use the `Application Loader` that I have downloaded separately from Itunes Connect instead of the one that comes bundled with Xcode.